# how to iterate over 2 list, I want to replace list_1 element with list_2 element on the same indexing of list_2

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list_1 = ['first name','class_1','section_1','middle name','last name','subject 1','subject 2','subject 3']
list_2 = ['first name','middle_name','last name','subject_1','subject_2','subject_3','section 1','class 1']

output = ['first name','middle name','last name','subject 1','subject 2','subject 3','section_1','class_1']
```

if common element then position should be list_2
else pick list_1 element and replace with list_2 on same indexing of list_2
We can have new list also.

Comment: the output is not just list_2?

Comment: if you observe then correct column name picked from list_1